# Why this is true; $P(X<a) = P(e^{X}<e^{a})$?

Tags: probability

This may be an obvious questions but for me I don't see the solution right-away, so I am posting this question here.

Why the following identity is true?
$$
P(X<a)  = P(e^X<e^a)
$$ 
where $X$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the exponential function  is increasing hence the events $[X\lt a]$ and $[e^X\lt e^a]$ coincide.

Answer (score 2):

The function $f(x)=e^x$ is monotonically increasing. $x_2 > x_1 \Longleftrightarrow e^{x_2}>e^{x_1}$

Answer (score 0):

Because $e^x > e^y, \forall x, y \in \mathbb R$, such that $x > y$.

I think function having this property is called a strictly increasing function.

Comment: Downvoter, what is the reason?

Comment: I do not know the reason but this only provides an inequality instead of the desired equality.